# Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' from node module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I've been having this issue with Jest. Jest is throwing an error pointing towards a dependency from within node_modules. Probably need to configure jest to support this syntax, because it can't parse it. But i'm not sure what for configurations.

I've tried to add transformIgnorePatterns in the jest.config.ts file with no luck,

```
    "node_modules/(?!(geotiff)/)"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
Details:

    /Users/Documents/Project/node_modules/quick-lru/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export default class QuickLRU extends Map {
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/geotiff/dist-module/source/blockedsource.js:1:1)
```

This is the jest.config.ts

```
// jest.config.ts
import type {Config} from "@jest/types";

const config : Config.InitialOptions = {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "!**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
  ],
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.(test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testEnvironmentOptions": {
    "url" :  "http://localhost"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/typescriptTransform.js",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(geotiff)/)"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "web.ts",
    "ts",
    "web.tsx",
    "tsx",
    "web.js",
    "js",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node",
    "mjs"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "./tsconfig.test.json"
    }
  },
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/src/"
  ]
};
```

this is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "files": [
    "build/**/*"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.14.0",
    "npm": ">=8.11.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ssh://Project},
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "sass --style=compressed -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:/src --watch",
    "start-js": "node scripts/start.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "debug": "npm-run-all -p --inspect=9227 watch-css start-js",
    "prebuild": "cross-env CI=true npm run test --watchAll=false",
    "build": "npm run build-css && node scripts/build.js",
    "postbuild": "node scripts/zip.js",
    "build-test": "npm run build-css node scripts/build.js",
    "serve-build": "npm run serve -s build",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "preversion": "CI=true npm run test",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/ESLint -c .eslintrc.js -o ./lint.log"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.12",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-autocomplete": "^1.8.6",
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.1.5",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/react-highlight": "^0.12.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.7",
    "adm-zip": "^0.5.9",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.7",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "chalk": "5.0.1",
    "classnames": "~2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv": "16.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.11",
    "fs-extra": "10.1.0",
    "geotiff": "^2.0.5",
    "html-webpack-injector": "^1.1.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "neo-async": "^2.6.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "ol": "~6.14.1",
    "ol-ext": "^3.2.26",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "proj4": "^2.5.0",
    "promise": "^8.0.1",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.0",
    "react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-highlight": "^0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "^1.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "sneakpeek-cli": "^0.2.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "webpack": "~5.73.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0"
  },
}
```